# React Native - Render A List in Select Component from native-base

Tags: react-native, native-base

I used select component from native-base :

```js
import { Select } from 'native-base';
```

Fake Data :

```js
const OgrenciData = [
    {key: '3', name: 'Emre', jobTitle: 'Pc', email: 'Emre.Sanli'},
    {key: '5', name: 'Harun', jobTitle: 'Pc', email: 'Emre.Sanli'},
];
```

My Select Component is like this :

```js
<Select
  selectedValue={baskanOgrenci}
  minWidth="200"
  accessibilityLabel="Giriş Türü"
  placeholder="Giriş Türü"
  mt={1}
  onValueChange={itemValue => setBaskanOgrenci(itemValue)}>
</Select>
```

I have tried copying from FlatList component but it didn't work :(

I want my code to be like this if possible :

```js
{({OgrenciData}) => {
    return (
      <Select.Item
        label={OgrenciData.key}
        value={OgrenciData.key}
      />
    );
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the map function like this:

```js
{OgrenciData.map(x => {
    return (
      <Select.Item
        label={x.key}
        value={x.key}
      />
    );
})}
```